# assign an array to kusto table

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer

I'm trying to assign an array of strings into a datatable but I'm not sure what's wrong with the syntax.

code:

```
let array=dynamic(["", ""]);
let table= datatable(id:string) array;//error here Expected: [
```

Answer (score 0):

So the way I solved it is by:
let table= datatable(id:string) ["", ""]